Is it recoginzed as safe wiring rear camera
Most rear dash cam install videos have the wiring for the rear dash cam running under the headliner, around the front of the a-pillar, around the top rubber trim of the front door, around the front of the b-pillar, around the top rubber trim of the rear door, and finally around the front of the rear pillar...
This wiring scheme will not interfere with side curtain airbag deployments?

Yes, no, maybe? Depends on specifics of your vehicle. For a rear camera or other stuff to the rear, I've never run it that way. Your mileage may vary.

The most “professional” way to install wiring for a rear view camera is to pull the headliner and run the data cable above the headliner. This keeps it out of the way of anything that it would otherwise interfere with. If the vehicle is equipped with a sunroof or moonroof find an existing harness that runs along the side of the roof and use electrical tape to secure it to the side of that harness conduit. If there is not other harness above the headliner but a moonroof or sunroof is present secure the data cable in a way that it will never contact the sunroof cover track or the sunroof glass or hinges.
Really at the end of the day running it like you described can add safety risks and just annoyance and inconvenience. If you lack the skill to pull the headliner properly the best way to route the data cable is from the source > down the a pillar trim panel > under passenger or driver kick plate > under scuff plate > under rear scuff plate > up b or c pillar trim panel and then go from there.

I was looking at pulling the headliner. Thanks for confirmation. Note, I also did find some videos of professionals and they  pulled the plastic from the pillar and secured it around existing wiring then ran it all along the floor. They stayed clear of the airbags.
